# PDO::rollback after using prepared statement

Tags: pdo, commit, rollback

I understand that in order to prevent injection attack, PDO::prepare first sends the query to the server then the parameters go later; Now, I feel this introduces another problem: that implies there cannot be rollback after PDO::execute, or am I missing something?

I have two tables 1 and 2 in an application. The two tables are not supposed to contain the same row. When I use INSERT INTO table1 SELECT FROM Table2, I want to DELETE FROM table2 if the INSERT query succeeds. And if either of the queries fails, I want to rollback. So I have the following code:

```
$dbConn->beginTransaction();

$stmt1 = $dbConn->prepare( "INSERT INTO table1 ( field1, field2, field3  )   
        SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table2 WHERE field4 = :field4" );

$stmt1->execute( array( $field4 ) );

$stmt2 = $dbConn->prepare( "DELETE FROM table2 WHERE field4 = :field4" );

$stmt2->execute( array( $field4 ) );

if ( $stmt1->rowCount() > 0 && $stmt2->rowCount() > 0 )
{   
    $dbConn->commit();

    return true;
}
else
{
    $dbConn->rollBack();

    return false;
}
```

Without prepared statement, this is very easy; but with it, it looks like difficult; has anyone done something like this before?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think prepare makes a difference? Transactions deal with the table data.

Comment: What's the difficulty?

Answer (score -1):

This isn't difficult and from what I can tell should work fine. However I would restructure the code to use exceptions:

```
try {
  $dbConn->beginTransaction();

  $stmt1 = $dbConn->prepare( "INSERT INTO table1 ( field1, field2, field3  )   
        SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table2 WHERE field4 = :field4" );

  $stmt1->execute( array( $field4 ) );

  $stmt2 = $dbConn->prepare( "DELETE FROM table2 WHERE field4 = :field4" );

  $stmt2->execute( array( $field4 ) );


    if ( $stmt1->rowCount() > 0 && $stmt2->rowCount() > 0 )
    {   
      $dbConn->commit();
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      throw new LogicException('Unequal row counts.');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
     $dbConn->rollBack();
      if ($e instanceof LogicException) {
         // just return
         return false;
      } else {
        // otherwise rethrow because something we didnt expect to go
        // wrong did
        throw $e;
      }
}
```

This way we also roll back if something else generates an exception like `PDO` or some other thing we may be doing as part of our data preparation.